# Is there a way to combine background-size:contain and :cover?

Tags: css, background-size

I want to use `background-size:contain` and `background-size:cover` at the same time. I want to have my background image stretch 100% width x 100% height of the browser window at all times while maintaining the scale of the image.

[Here is a perfect example of what I'm trying to do](http://rawww.com/)

Is there a pure css route to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="page-section clear">
     <div class="landing_photo clear" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/tempory_landing.png');">

    </div>
</div>

.page-section {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
.landing_photo {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In-line styling is not great, so first of all I would put your image `url` in the CSS file.

Second, you need to assign a fixed value to height and width to `.landing_photo`.

This the resulting CSS for achieving what you want:

```
.page-section {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
.landing_photo {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-position:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg);
}
```

and the markup

```
<div class="page-section clear">
    <div class="landing_photo clear"></div>
</div>
```

I have created a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tufwLvre/)** for you.

Comment: The image URL is generated via PHP, in which case it can only be inline.